# how i write Like statement for create an cursor on My special Folder?

Tags: android, cursor, directory, mediastore

I am programming for android and I have get all audios details on the SDcard.I have this question:

how i write Like statement for create an cursor on My special Folder?
I dont want cursor access to all external.only on my folder.I want limit cursoring.but how?with which LIKE Statemet?

```
 Cursor audioCursor = ((Activity)context ). managedQuery(audiosUri,star,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] { folderpath }, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I do it.  when a user long clicks, a query is executed against the music database. _DATA holds the fully qualified path for each song so the query will return all the files in that folder.
path is         path = new ArrayList(); which was built up by path.add(file.getPath());
You will find many examples on how to display folder and files.

```
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int row, long arg3) {
            String criteria = path.get(row);
            int criterialength = criteria.length();
            int lastslash = criteria.lastIndexOf("/");
            String suggestedname = criteria.substring(lastslash + 1,
                    criterialength);
            String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ?";
            criteria = "%" + criteria + "%";// looking for path string in
                                            // DATA of database
        // now get your cursor similar to shown below and do something with it
            return true;
        }
    });


public Cursor getCriteriacursor(Context context, Cursor cursor,
        String where, String criteria) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    String[] strcriteria = { criteria };
    final String[] columns = { track_id, track_no, artist, track_name,
            album, duration, year, composer };
    cursor = cr.query(uri, columns, where, strcriteria, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: why cursor is not closed??dont should close it?

Comment: you close it once you have used it. Usually, once you have your folder selected, you loop by cursor.movefirst(), cursor.movenext() etc.when you no longer need this cursor then you close it cursor.close()

Comment: And I had before used from cursor.I used before from Cursor only.i needed to a Like statement. And using from ContentResolver instead of which I write for code in my question is better.I dosnt test your code yet But If you are certain for correcting and usefuling your code talk to me for accept your answer.i just need Like Statement.thanks thanks thanks anyway dear...